# DIV for modal display that has fixed header and footer, scrollable content, and no fixed pixel values for content height

Tags: css

I have been stumped on how to create a DIV for a modal display that uses a fixed header and footer, scrollable content area, and relies solely on percentage values for width/height of the holder and the content body. Disclaimer: I do not know much about CSS.

Here is what I want:

- DIV with 65% width, 60% height, centered on page

  - Header: 100px tall, fixed position
  - Content: Whatever is left in the DIV tall, fixed position, scrollable content
  - Footer: 100px tall, fixed position

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq5yC/)

Here's my attempt:

```
html, mbody {
    overflow:auto;
}

#mholder{
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width:  65%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
}

#mheader{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}

#mbody{
    width:100%;
}

#mfooter{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

Here's what I have on the page:

```
<div id="mholder">
    <div id="mheader">Header text</div>
    <div id="mbody">Long body text...</div>
    <div id="mfooter">Footer text</div>
</div>
```

What's happening is that the header is appearing in the very top-left of my *page*, not the modal display; ditto for the footer on the bottom-right; the modal area (which should be identified by a white background) is definitely not 65%/60% of the page, and the `mbody` html is kind of overlapping the `mholder` div haphazardly.

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq5yC/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a

```
position : absolute;
```

instead of `fixed` for your header and your footer.
Fixed is relative to the screen, when absolute and relative are actually dependent on the last layer with a non-static position.

A fiddle would be appreciated.

EDIT: Does [that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uq5yC/6/) look more like what you expected ?
So it seems like the `position: absolute` suited your needs for the position of the header and the footer.

So you just needed to do the same for the body to position it perfectly. But then you face a new problem. You wanted your header and footer to have a fixed size, but want the body to fill the 'rest'.
I cannot possibly think of a solution to do that, except by giving to the header and footer a height in percentage. That's what I did in my fiddle.
So that's the best I could find.

All three elements are `absolute`ly positioned, the header positioned with a `top: 0;`, the body with the `top: 10%;` instruction, and the footer with a `bottom: 0;`.

Comment: Added a fiddle and implemented your suggestion, it's looking closer! I also made the bg color of the holder grey so that it could be distinguished from the page surrounding it. http://jsfiddle.net/Uq5yC/

Comment: And added long body text, but it doesn't seem to be handling that so well :)

Comment: there are a lot of attributes you can remove but here is what i got http://jsfiddle.net/Cy2B5/12/

Comment: I edited my post so that it matches more your needs. I'm adding right now some explanations about what I added.

Comment: Yes, it does - that's right. Looking forward to your explanation, in particular why `mheader` and `mfooter` ignore the `mholder`'s `padding` but `mbody` respects it

Comment: That's because of the position absolute. The body doesn't respect the padding, I forced it with the `top: 10%;`.

Comment: Gotcha. I have to say that my understanding of `absolute` and `fixed` was completely the opposite of what they evidently mean. Thanks very much